# How to hide SharePoint field from users

Tags: sharepoint-server

Hey I want to hide one important field(TestC) from users. Approves group only look at that field. I just tried using js, But it doesn't work. Need help

```
<script src="/Shared%20Documents/Jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Shared%20Documents/SPService.js"></script>

<script>
// wait for the window to load
$(document).ready(function() {
$().SPServices({
operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
async: false,
   completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
   var xml = xData.responseXML.xml;

//hiding email address column from users except sharepoint group

if(xml.search('mcsp_sp-admin') == -1)

 {
     var TestCField = $("input[title=TestC]");
     EmailAddressField.parent().parent().parent().hide();       
}
 }
 });

 });

</script>
```

Comment: ♦ If an answer was helpful could you remove your question from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery or SPServices

Since IE9 (and Chrome long before) there is the native TreeWalker API

Answered before here on StackOverflow with long explanation

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=hide+field+treewalker

---

Yes, it looks longer compared to cryptic jQuery code,
but you are **not** loading 2 very large libraries

**All** the JavaScript required:

```
var formCSI = function (form){

function getComments(element) {
    function acceptNode() {     // IE *requires* this argument where other browsers don't.
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }

    var safeFilter = acceptNode;// IE *requires* this argument where other browsers don't.
    safeFilter.acceptNode = acceptNode;
    return document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT, safeFilter, false);
}

  var tree=getComments(form);
  while (node=tree.nextNode()) {//loop all found <!-- comments -->
    eval(node.nodeValue.replace(/ Field/g, ';var CSI_') + ';');//convert comment to vars
    console.info(CSI_InternalName,CSI_Type,CSI_Name);
    var TR=node;while (TR.tagName !== 'TR') TR = TR.parentNode;//find parent TR row
    this[CSI_InternalName]=TR;// store TR as formCSI.[internalName] eg. formCSI.Title
  }
  return this;//return formCSI as object
}(document.querySelector('.ms-formtable'));//IIFE execute function immediatly

//formCSI now is an object referencing all Form Row TR elements
formCSI.Title.style.background='pink';
formCSI.AssignedTo.style.display='none';// 'table-row' to show again
```

---

#### Apply to a Group of User

No need for Javascript code at all

Do it the SharePoint way, add above code to a CEWP and use the WebPart property **target audience** to only execute it for certain users

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the `search` function to `Find` as shown below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $().SPServices({
 operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
 userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
 async: false,
 completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

 //If the current User does belong to the group "SharePoint Group Name"
 if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Qassas Group']").length == 1)
 {

 $('nobr:contains("TestC")').closest('tr').hide();
 } else
 {
 $('nobr:contains("TestC")').closest('tr').show();
 }
 }
 });
});
</script>
```

For more details check

- [Show / hide fields based on choice field selection using jquery in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)
- [Show / hide fields based on a dropdown selection using sputility.js](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)
- [SHOW / HIDE A DIV TAG BASED ON A USER GROUP IN SHAREPOINT VIA SPSERVICES](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-div-based-user-group-in-sharepoint-via-spservices/)

Comment: I tried , but not working.

Comment: Have you replaced your group name and all variables with your own variable?

Comment: I only changed Group name ,SP service and JQ library.

Comment: paste here your new code !

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

     $().SPServices({
     operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
     userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
     async: false,
     completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

    //If the current User does belong to the group "SharePoint Group 
    Name"
     if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='MCSP 
    Members']").length == 1)
     {

     $('nobr:contains("TestC")').closest('tr').show();
     } else
     {
     $('nobr:contains("TestC")').closest('tr').hide();
     }
     }
 });
});

Comment: from your code I only change the name of the group .

Comment: what's your field name and what's the type of your form is it New form?

Comment: The name of the column is "TestC" and I created new form.aspx which is called TestNewForm.aspx and make it default .Thanks

Comment: Okay i applied the above code on default form so let me try it in my side for custom form and check if it's working or not !!

Comment: Try using SPUtility.js. It has a Hide() function that handles this mess for you.