# Hiding Columns from users except managers

Tags: sharepoint-server

I just tried using jq and put under edit snippet. Here is the code.

```
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="https:/SiteAssets/jquery.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https/SiteAssets/sputility.js">
</script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="https:/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-
2014.02.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

 $().SPServices({
 operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
 userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
 async: false,
 completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

 //If the current User does belong to the group "Translation Managers"
 if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='Translation Managers']").length 
    == 1)
 {
    $('nobr:contains("TestC")').closest('tr').show();
 } else
 {
    $('nobr:contains("TestC")').closest('tr').hide();
 }
}
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214888/how-to-hide-sharepoint-field-from-users

Comment: Ok Let me look ate